# Improving the performance of merging two ArrayLists

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, arraylist, merge

I am merging two `ArrayList`s with the following code. The code is working and giving me the desired result, but I want a more efficient version. Here are the conditions.

1. Method accepts two lists, and both list have elements in decreasing order (5,4,3,2)
2. Method accepts an integer to decide the size of the resulting `ArrayList`.
3. First input list size is never greater than the size of the resulting `ArrayList`.

Code:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> mergeList(ArrayList<Integer> first,ArrayList<Integer> second, int n){
    //case 1: when both list are null.
    if(first == null && second == null )
        return null;
    //case 2: when first list is null but second list have elements
    else if( first == null && second != null){
        return second.size() >=n ? new ArrayList<Integer>(second.subList(0, n)) : second;
    }
    //case 3: when first list have record and second list is null
    else if(first != null && second == null){
        return first;
    }
    //case 4: when both list have elements 
    else {
        first.addAll(second);
        Collections.sort(first);
        Collections.reverse(first);
        return first.size()>=n ? new ArrayList<Integer>(first.subList(0, n)) : first;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is needlessly complex.  `ArrayList` expands as needed, so there's no need to pre-allocate it (parameter `int n` is not needed); you should just allocate the result list once, at the beginning. I think the objective here was to write a proper merge.  Concatenating the lists and sorting will not be the best solution.  If for some reason you still want to do this, sort in descending order to begin with so you don't have to reverse the list.

Comment: @JimGarrison parameter n is the part of requirement so I can not avoid it, but I took your advice for and update my code. the latest code is uploaded.

Comment: Is the resulting list also required to be in reverse order? Are duplicates allowed, in either the inputs or the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "More efficient".

In terms of what?  Memory, CPU, readability?

Based on your code above, I'm making the following assumptions:

- Readability is more important than pure performance/memory consumption without any profiling measurements/requirements "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet." — Michael A. Jackson
- Prefer the null object pattern over returning null
- Duplicate elements are desirable/required
- Use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to perform a reverse
  sort

---

```
private List<Integer> mergeList(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2, final int newSize) {

    // Enforce null object pattern
    if (list1 == null) {
        list1 = Collections.emptyList();
    }
    if (list2 == null) {
        list2 = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    // If duplicates are not desirable, a TreeSet would perform automatic sorting.
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
    result.addAll(list2);

    Comparator<Integer> reverseSortComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(result, reverseSortComparator);

    if (result.size() > newSize) {
        return result.subList(0, newSize);
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking to implement

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to preserve the contents of `first` and `second`. If you are not, then this will do just fine for you and will make your code both faster and more readable:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> mergeList(ArrayList<Integer> first,ArrayList<Integer> second, int maxLength){

    //case 1: when both list are null.
    if(first == null && second == null )
        return null;
    //case 2: when first list is null but second list have elements
    else if( first == null && second != null){
        return second;
    }
    //case 3: when first list have record and second list is null
    else if(first != null && second == null){
        return first;
    }
    //case 4: when both list have elements 
    else if(first != null && second != null){
        first.addAll(second);
        Collections.sort(first); //want to merge these two line into one
        Collections.reverse(first);
    }
    return (ArrayList) first.size() > maxLength ? first.subList(0, n) : first;
}
```

The reason why this is faster is because with each `addAll()`, Java must iterate through all the items, copying them into `tempList`. I preserved the `Collections.reverse` call because it seems like you need to have your data in reverse sorted order.

Comment: nope I am not trying to preserve the content of first and second but I do want to return the list of size n, the third argument of my list.

Comment: @Ashish, I re-added the truncation step. This would trim off the smallest elements in the list, leaving the list no greater than length `maxLength`.

Comment: thanks but subList(0,n) will be returning List not the arraylist.

Comment: @Ashish, an `ArrayList` "isa" `List`. Just cast it back to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I tried, though I have updated my code with what you are trying to say

Comment: @Ashish I have also updated my answer to match what I'm trying to say.  Don't declare a new instance of `ArrayList`, just cast it.